# Realm deletes other so files from the apk

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, realm

My project includes jni folder.
The project compiles and running just fine. After including Realm in the project, it compiles but doesn't run.
The problem is - Realm deletes my so file from the apk when it add his own.

How can I fix the problem and include both so files?

Comment: What IDE are you using? How did you add Realm to your project? through gradle or jar file?

Comment: I'm using android studio and gradle (compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.80.1')

Comment: Realm does nothing to delete your other .so files. I'm suspecting an issue with the Android Gradle plugin from Google.

Comment: I tried with this case, it works fine. I packed a armeabi-v7a so into a jar, and put it into libs dir. After compiling with the realm, both so files are in the apk dir. Is it possible your own so file has the same name with realm's?

Comment: Thank you for your help! My file didn't have the same name as realm's, my problem was that I didn't have the armeabi-v7a folder, just armeabi.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

add "APP_ABI := all" in Application.mk file, 
add in src\main\libs armeabi-v7a folder to also have the so file in it